# Show post based on the value of another custom field

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

How do you display posts based on the value of one of its custom fields? My code below doesn't seem to work:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'sample-cpt',
    'meta_query ' => array(array('key'=>'cpt_display', 'value' => 1))
);
$samples = new WP_Query($args);
```

This still returns all posts even if the value of `cpt_display` is a `0`. Am I missing something?

Comment: The 'value' parameter should be either of type string or of type array. Try changing `'value' => 1` to `'value' => '1'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Adding the meta_key = key as part of the args, 
then include it again in the meta_query array

```
 $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'sample-cpt',
   'meta_key' => 'key',
   'order' => 'ASC',
   'meta_query' => array(
       array(
           'key' => 'key',
           'value' => 1
       )
   )
 );
 $samples = new WP_Query($args);
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The value of `'meta_value'` needs to be an array not a string. This is a huge deviation from the [WP_Query Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and needs to be fixed.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'sample-cpt',
    'meta_key' => 'cpt_display',
    'meta_value' => array(1)
);
$samples = new WP_Query($args);
wp_reset_query();
```

Now it only shows posts with the custom field value of `1`. Looking at the request query, it shows that by using an array, the request gets converted into using the SQL `IN()` to search for posts instead of `'='`:

```
...postmeta.meta_key='cpt_display' AND CAST(postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) IN ('1'))...
```

Source: [Display custom post type by custom field date range](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-custom-post-type-by-custom-field-date-range#post-2797124)